# Without advanced technologies, how good at biology could ruthless scientists be?

Tags: medical

I have a world technologically set in the bronze age (But there's plenty of utilitarian "magic" by a highly advanced culture, so resources are not scarce at all) and there's a crazy technophiliac cult that hates magic and wants to prove everything works through science (Whatever they mean by that), so some of them decide that the best way to learn about the body is to do live vivisections on other humans.

So my question is : How close to modern biology, physiology, anatomy etc. could these cultists get with this method, enough time and without electricity, microscopes, hypodermic needles etc.?

Comment: Considering that bronze-age folks spent most of their daylight fending off starvation working subsistence agriculture, and tended to die rather young, it's impressive that enough nutters found each other to form a weird-science-cult in the first place. Without the fundamentals of scientific inquiry, their butchery won't get them far. Note that the local police (or the local Warlord's goons) probably know who these nutters are, so carved-up neighbors won't present an unsolvable mystery.

Comment: @user535733 As I said, they have plenty of utility magic, so the resource part is taken care of, meaning they have the time and health to do stupid stuff. Secondly, the nutters in question live in a big city and are mostly members of the same family, so its not *that* far-detched by my standards. I'm really interested by your "no fundamentals of scientific inquiry" though; You think that's gonna slow the research down to practically 0 discoveries?

Comment: Keep in mind this was basically true for much of history, the thing that help back science was poor methodology not lack of vivisection. Vivisection did not fall out of usage until the modern age. So basically nothing changes. what needed to change was a focus on peer review, fallibility, and application of logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How close to modern biology, physiology, anatomy etc. could these cultists get with this method, enough time and without electricity, microscopes, hypodermic needles etc.?

Hard no on biology, but somewhere decent in anatomy and physiology, though in weird ways. Assuming a really large supply of live subjects and axe-crazed scientists who have no ethical concerns, they'd be able to figure out all the organs in the human body with decent efficiency. It would take them longer to figure out what said organs do, but once they figure out that the heart and brain are *really* important to human life and everything else isn't as important, they could form a rough hierarchy of importance by removing the other organs and seeing how long it takes people to die and what symptoms they show when that happen.

For instance, removing the liver causes people to die pretty quickly and feel absolutely horrible while that happens but the spleen seems to have little effect except people missing a spleen get sicker more often. Although, you know, this being the *Bronze Age*, this is barely noticeable and will probably require a dive into statistics to prove it, but eventually, using the method of 'remove the organ and see what happens' will give you a *rough* idea of how important the organ is / what the organ does, assuming you go through enough corpses to accomplish it. Which, by the way, will be in the thousands, at minimum. I'm not sure where you're getting all these people from, considering that it's the Bronze Age, but it's doable.

Oh, and you'll have to learn how to perform surgery to do this, which is possible with Bronze Age tools, but it'll have to be learned how to do, in other words they'll quickly (or not so quickly) learn that cutting people apart works best with clean tools (as in, alcohol - cleaned tools), in a clean room with trained surgeons. You'll still lose people to hideous infections, so you'll have to be able to determine when people die from raging infection or when they die from missing lung, which will take even more corpses. And meticulous record keeping and statistical analysis of this record keeping.

You might even be able to come up with theories about germs, these invisible things that cause disease and infections, based on all these observations, and the knowledge that there are also things ongoing in the human body that you can't just yet explain. But you'll be able to catalog every part of the body that can be seen and what it does. Though you'll be standing atop a literal mountain of corpses when you do that, (and have invented statistics!) so I'm not quite certain this would be ethical.

Not to mention that you can't *treat* anything. Sure, you'll have learned the basics of hygiene, but when people get sick, you can say 'Well, he's having difficulty breathing so the disease must be in the lungs. But we don't know how to treat this disease, aside from removing the lungs, but the last several hundred times that happened the person died, so we don't recommend it.' On the flip side, you will also now know what a terrible idea bleeding people is. In other words, you'll have the equivalent knowledge of a high-school student who slept through biology but managed to cram the class nerd's notes on anatomy.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer!

Comment: Note that without modern statistical analysis, the psychopaths are likely to make conclusions based on "instinctive" pattern recognition and leap to the wrong conclusions.  Then base the next chain in their logic on a false premise and never get a genuine understanding of why anything is happening.

Comment: If there's any confirmation bias whatsoever present, that would be very bad, yes.

Answer (score 1):

They could probably get to the level of knowing that bacteria exist, and they could map out the nervous system and learn about the brain. Anything past that, I think would need some advanced tools to work with the materials.